# Inline-Block inside position:absolute element

Tags: html, css, css-position

My question is simple: what happens to inline-block elements inside of absolutely positioned elements? I have a little example to illustrate what I mean. It's hard to explain otherwise. The question is why the `.icon` inside of the `.tag` is not positioned like the previous `.icon` (that is, *inline* and to the right of the text)

The code below can be viewed @ http://jsbin.com/itole4/5

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .field { position: relative; border: 2px solid black;}
        .tag   { position: absolute; left: 100%; top: -2px; background: black; color: white;}
        .icon  { width:16px;height:16px; display: inline-block; background: gray; text-indent: -999px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <a>Some text <span class='icon'>X</span> </a>
    <h2>
        <span class='field'>Some Text<span class='tag'> tag<span class='icon'>x</span></span></span>
    </h2>
    <h2>
        <span class='field'>Some Text</span>
    </h2>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It could be because you are not closing all the spans.

this line is missing one </span>: 

<span class='field'>Some Text<span class='tag'> tag<span class='icon'>x</span></span>

Comment: Good observation, this doesn't solve the problem though. I think Chrome is smart enough to close that tag when it sees the `</h2>`.

Comment: You could try defining a width for .tag to make sure it isn't wrapping around.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, the icon is acting exactly the same. To test, try setting a's style to

```
display: inline-block; width: 50px;
```

When you make a tag position: absolute, it causes the tag to no longer have an automatic width of 100% of its parent, but rather to have the minimal width it can take according to heuristics within the browser (browser-dependent). The inline block acts like "inline", like an image, and is thus wrapped to the next line at the first chance (which is right after the word "tag").

So the short answer is: the icon is acting the same, but the block containing it is not.

In order to force the icon on the same line, as on the first line, you can add `white-space: pre;`. See: http://jsbin.com/itole4/6 (also see comment below)

Comment: Thank you! I did not know that `position:absolute` messed with the width. Is there any way to make the `.icon` show up next to "tag" without setting the width to a fixed size?

Comment: Yes, you can do "[white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/white-space): pre;" to force-prevent line breaks except at <br> tags. Obviously, this would prevent you from keeping the text fluid. An alternative may be to wrap just the label and icon in a span that has white-space set to pre, which would then limit the damage to areas where you need things in that way.

Comment: @Sajid I experienced a similarly obscure/abstract problem (at least to me) with a link whereby the text dropped below the icon once positioning was applied. The white-space suggestion resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

because the `.field` has position `relative` and if you will add the `.icon` with style : `position:absolute;top:0px;` inside of the `.field` the `.icon` will be added on  '0px' on top of the `.field` not of `body`

**I can't explain it better in English >.<**, i hope you can understand

Answer (score 0):

it's not the positioning - it's the element containing  the "icon" class..in one you've got a plain `inline` `a` the other a nested setup where the parent is an block level `h2` this means your "inline-bock" has different line-heights and vertical alignment